# calculating the probability of an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are $5$ male students and $4$ female students are lined up. Calculates the probability of always placing a row of more than $2$ male students between $2$ female students.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: This question can be answered in multiple ways. I am assuming by your use of the word "always" that this experiment is repeated ad nauseum. With probability 100%, you will eventually have an arrangement which does not have the requirement you specified. In other words, there is a 0% chance that you will "always" place a row of more than 2 male students between 2 female students.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have the following in mind: $9$ people ($5$ boys and $4$ girls) are put into a random order. What is the probability that we see at least three successive boys?

(Of course your text is far away from this, but some other possible interpretations clearly have probability $0$.)

There are $9!$ equiprobable arrangements of the $9$ people.

We now count the number of boys/girls arrangements containing a subrow of at least $3$ boys. Line up the girls with ample intermediate space as follows:
$$-\ \bullet\ -\ \bullet\ -\ \bullet\ -\ \bullet\ -$$
There are $5$ slots where we can squeeze in a  subrow of three circles $\ \circ\>\circ\>\circ\>$. Then we can distribute the remaining two circles in ${2+5-1\choose 5-1}={6\choose2}=15$ ways into the $5$ slots. It follows that there are $5\cdot15=75$ arrangements of $4$ bullets and $5$ circles containing a subrow of $\geq3$ circles. Given any of these arrangements the $5$ boys and $4$ girls can be placed accordingly in $5!\cdot4!$ ways. The required probability therefore is
$${75\cdot5!\cdot4!\over9!}={25\over42}\ .$$